# Centralizar Bloco de texto na vertical de acordo com o tamanho da div ao lado

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout

Meus parceiros, estou perdendo os cabelos com este problema que estou enfrentando.

Tenho algumas páginas feitas com bootsptrap, no qual cada container possui uma linha (row) e a mesma possui duas colunas (cada uma com as classes: col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6), nisso as linhas vão se alternando entre texto/imagem e imagem/texto onde o valor de Height usado como referência é o da imagem(geralmente é maior que os blocos de texto), nisso eu pego o valor da imagem, pego o height do bloco de texto, subtraio e divido o valor por 2 para chegar na margen-top para só assim poder centralizar verticalmente os blocos de texto de acordo com o centro da imagem.

Eu fiz uns gatos e não sei se a lógica seria essa: http://jsfiddle.net/9Lsst0gx/

A coisa em si funciona, o problema porém é que o código só funciona quando damos um refresh na página, quando a carregamos novamente. Ele não funciona quando abrimos pela primeira vez e este é o problema pois ele deve centralizar assim que a página for carregada.

Alguém poderia me indicar qual o meu erro ou se possível uma forma de solucionar?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente adicionar isso ao final:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    WszW = $(window).width();
    gTCP(WszW);
});
```

Caso seu JS esteja antes das imagens ou antes do tamanho da janela ser resolvido, isso vai garantir que ele atualize a largura ao final do carregamento da página, e que ele execute a função novamente, com a largura definida.

Comment: Fernando meu amigo, primeiramente muito obrigado pela sua ajuda e pelo seu tempo em me ajudar. Cara, resolveu perfeitamente... muito obrigado meu parceiro, era uma coisa tão simples que estava bem de baixo do meu nariz. Agora esta tudo resolvido. Muito obrigado meu amigo. Valeu

Comment: Leandro meu caro, não há de quê! Fico feliz em poder ajudar. E seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. :D